# How to split up embedded Ruby string in shell command

Tags: bash

Writing a web2py on Cloud SQL boon using Gitbookl. It contains the following line of OSX bash shell code:

```
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
```

Would like to shorten the display to 40-60 characters per line while still allowing the user to copy and paste the code in. All of my experiments are failing, but obviously I want to do something like this:

```
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL\
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/\
Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
```

No longer a Ruby guy and am at wit's end. Can someone tell me how to get a copy/pasteable line like this into my markdown?

(The general problem is that ebooks are limited to 40-60 columns in code printouts, and I need a way to handle long paths and long paths.)

Comment: Aren't you just missing the whitespace? e.g. ` -fsSL \ `. Otherwise it all gets munged together as one long run-on argument.

Comment: THAT'S IT! I love you and want to have your babies! Thank you so much, steeldriver!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do:

```
$ curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/\
Homebrew/install/master/uninstall|ruby
```

Comment: Nice! Was trying to avoid curl though because it's not built into OS X. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should to the trick..

```
domain="raw.githubusercontent.com"
url="Homebrew/install/master/uninstall"

ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://${domain}/${url})"
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. So sorry for the tardy reply, DopeGhoti!

Comment: Pleased to have been able to help!

Answer (score 1):

[steeldriver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/65304/steeldriver) nailed it. The answer was to insert a space before the slash at the end of the first line, so:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL \
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/\
Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
```

That can indeed be copy and pasted right into the shell prompt.

As soon as the Nobel committee sees fit to make me one of their own I am going to nominate steeldriver for something.

Comment: Specifically, *"Since the escaped <newline> is removed entirely from the input and is not replaced by any white space, it cannot serve as a token separator."*: see [2.2.1 Escape Character (Backslash)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_02_01)